# surface integral odd surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find the surface area of $$z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$$ cut off by $$x^2+y^2=2x$$ Using $x=r*\cos(\theta)$, $y=r*\sin(\theta)$, $z=r$, I get the bound $0\leq r \leq 2\cos(\theta)$, $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$. $F(r,\theta)=(r \cos(\theta),r \sin(\theta),r)$.
I know that $$\int\int_{surface}d\sigma=\int\int_{D}||F_r \times F_{\theta}||_2dA$$. Where D is the region parameterized.

My question is, did I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct.

Check your $\theta$ interval. It should be
$$
-\frac{\pi}{2}\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2},
$$
as $x^2+y^2=x$ is in the $x\ge 0$ plane.